# How do i add formula in app script with data entry?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, formula

Hello everyone I having a problem related to my google sheet blow, I wrote a code script to run automated data entry, But I want to range(M:M)=> =ARRAYFORMULA(H8+I8+L8), when I put formula my data entry run to last row 1001. How to match it with my automated data entry or add other code script?

- Link Google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vQTKw4Kyzr6120TlGOSMN2gx5nM-pzq9MKpzYpImoD8/edit?usp=sharing
- My Apps Scripts code:

someone help me to fix this issue....

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But I want to range(M:M)=> =ARRAYFORMULA(H8+I8+L8), when I put formula my data entry run to last row 1001. How to match it with my automated data entry or add other code script?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I want to put auto formula column (H8+I8+L8) result to column M, and running with my automated data entry column A-F.